# h264 lossless mode in the Microsoft Media Foundation

Tags: video-streaming, ms-media-foundation

I found that the h264 codec can work in the lossless compression mode. But is the Microsoft Media Foundation supports it? If so, how can i switch the mode of compression from lossy to lossless for this codec?

Answer (score 4):

Software implementation of H.264 encoder shipped with Windows is limited in H.264 profiles and does not offer lossless encoding option. To my best knowledge, High 4:4:4 profile with lossless encoding option is available in x264 encoder, which however does not offer Media Foundation Transform form factor. With a respective wrapper Media Foundation API and x264 can be combined to produce losslessly encoded H.264 video with Media Foundation.

You can also have lossless encoding with NVIDIA hardware if you use their Video Codec SDK (aka "NVENC") and provide your own wrapper of a Media Foundation Transform over it.